# Create method on relationship not populating foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have 2 tables. My `price_rule_lookups` table stores a unique ID, and my `price_rule_products` table stores `product_id`s and a related foreign key to the `price_rule_lookups` table via `price_rule_lookup_id`. It is my understanding that

I am trying to use the `create` method to create related rows like so:

```
    $pl = PriceRuleLookup::create([
        'id' => $priceRuleId
    ]);

    $pl->products()->create([
        'product_id' => 123123
    ]);
```

It is my understanding that the `create` method on the relationship should populate the foreign key `price_rule_lookup_id`. However, whenever I run this code it fails due to a foreign key constraint as it is trying to populate the `price_rule_lookup_id` field with 0 no matter what.

Here are relevant models and migrations:

Price rule product model

```
class PriceRuleProduct extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'price_rule_lookup_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function rule(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PriceRuleLookup::class, 'price_rule_lookup_id');
    }
}
```

Price rule lookup model

```
class PriceRuleLookup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PriceRuleProduct::class);
    }
}
```

Price rule lookup table migration

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('price_rule_lookups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('price_rule_lookups');
    }
};
```

Price rule products table migration

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('price_rule_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreignId('price_rule_lookup_id');
            $table->foreign('price_rule_lookup_id')->references('id')->on('price_rule_lookups')
                ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('price_rule_products');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Since I am not using an auto-incrementing ID field for the `price_rule_lookups` table Laravel was having issues (this ID is coming from elsewhere and is always unique). I `dd`d the output of the initial create which was showing 0 which is how I figured it out.

Adding an `public $incrementing = false;` to the `PriceRuleLookup` model solved the issue.